# Поймать java Exception в python sl4a

Tags: python

Всем привет,есть скрипт в питоне:
    import android
    import time
    import inspect
    import sys

```
droid = android.Android()
droid.toggleBluetoothState(True)
id='457807c0-4897-11df-9879-0800200c9a66'
adr='D8:95:2F:42:3E:91'
try:
    result=droid.bluetoothConnect(id,adr)
except java.io.IOException:
    print 'lll'
```

droid.bluetoothConnect(id,adr) выбрасывает исключение,которых довольно много и они мусорят в консоле. Как перехватить вывод этих сообщений в консоль,стандартные блоки результатов не принесли.

Comment: Ловите Throwable, как прародителя оных

Answer (score 1):

Отлавливать нужно `java.lang.Exception` (а не `Throwable`) потому, что у `Throwable` есть ещё наследник `java.lang.Error`.

> `Error` - это подкласс, который показывает серьезные проблемы возникающие во время выполнения приложения. Большинство из этих ошибок сигнализируют о ненормальном ходе выполнения программы, т.е. о каких-то критических проблемах. ... Примерами таких исключений являются: `ThreadDeath`, `VirtualMachineError`, `OutOfMemoryError`.

[Источник](http://java-prompt.blogspot.com/2011/02/exception-error.html)

Скорее всего, все ошибки, которые мусорят в консоли являются наследниками `java.lang.Exception`. В противном случае нужно разбираться, почему они возникают.